# Converting Varchar2 to Date or Time_Stamp invalid month?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to convert a varchar2(30) of this format

```
10/10/2019 08:09:48 AM
```

into date_time or date so I can order it by start_time. I tried the following

```
SELECT MIN(TO_DATE(START_TIME,'MON/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS'))
```

I think it works because no syntax errors but I keep getting "not a valid month" that time structure up there is how the data looks I dont see an obscure date format.

Any ideas what the issue is?

this is for SQL ORACLE DEVELOPER

Comment: The format masks are explained in the Oracle documentation for function [TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MON` is for "Jan - Dec". Use `MM`:

```
SELECT MIN(TO_DATE(START_TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS'))
```

You will also need to account for your "AM/PM" part:

```
SELECT MIN(TO_DATE(START_TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'))
```

If this does not work out of the box, try explicitly setting the language to American:

```
SELECT MIN(TO_DATE(START_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'))
```

Comment: I am so stupid.... THANK YOU. I am now getting date format picture ends before converting entire input string is this due to the PM/AM part? also ill accept your answer in 9 minutes thanks :)

Comment: Option `'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'` is pointless if you don't have `MON` or `Month` in your format.